# SAS multiple datasets logical order

Tags: sas

I'm sorry to ask this question but my English is poor and I don't know what to type on google to get results.

I want to do :

```
data test;
set mytable1 to mytable999;
run;
```

how can I tell SAS to set all the tables from 1 to 999 without writing them (cause it's long to do so). something like mytable1-999

thank you very much, I know it's a basic function but I don't remember what is the name in English

Comment: The base/prefix parts of the name on both sides of the hyphen have to match.  `mytable1-mytable99`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the wild-card function of ´:´ in SAS. In

```
data myTable1;
    do i = 1 to 3;
        j = 2*i;
        output;
    end;
run;
data myTable2;
    do i = 1 to 3;
        j = -i;
        output;
    end;
run;
data myAll;
    set myTable:;
run;
```

`myTable:` is equivalent with the list of all tables of which the name starts with `myTable`.

The result is

```
i   j
==  ==
1   2
2   4
3   6
1   -1
2   -2
3   -3
```